# SPLoaderError.loadComponentError Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-server, spfx, error, spfx-webparts, gulp

I am trying to learn SPFx. I use SharePoint 2019. When I run "gulp serve", I found :

> Something went wrong
> If the problem persists, contact the site administrator and give them the information in Technical Details.
>
> TECHNICAL DETAILS:
>
> [SPLoaderError.loadComponentError]:
> Failed to load component "ded4a878-d57c-4432-ae97-9d059e3c7daa" (HelloWorldWebPart).
> Original error: Manifest not found for component id "73e1dc6c-8441-42cc-ad47-4bd3659f8a3a" and version "1.14.0".
>
> INNERERROR:
>
> Manifest not found for component id "73e1dc6c-8441-42cc-ad47-4bd3659f8a3a" and version "1.14.0".
>
> CALLSTACK:
> Error
> at t [as constructor] (https://ilmu.bpk.go.id/_layouts/15/next/spclient/en-us/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly.js?uniqueId=3kOKi:283:15766)
> at new t (https://ilmu.bpk.go.id/_layouts/15/next/spclient/en-us/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly.**js?uniqueId=3kOKi:914:22174)
> at Function.e.buildErrorWithVerboseLog (https://ilmu.bpk.go.id/_layouts/15/next/spclient/en-us/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly.js?uniqueId=3kOKi:914:14408)
> at Function.e.buildLoadComponentError (https://ilmu.bpk.go.id/_layouts/15/next/spclient/en-us/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly.js?uniqueId=3kOKi:914:10829)
> at https://ilmu.bpk.go.id/_layouts/15/next/spclient/en-us/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly.js?uniqueId=3kOKi:914:62084

How I can fix it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The most recent version of the SharePoint Framework will not work with SharePoint 2019. This means you need to install an older version of the SharePoint Framework Yeoman generator and older versions of the associated packages (Node.js, Gulp-CLI, and Yeoman). Specifically, you should install:

- Node.js v8.x
- Gulp CLI v2.3.0
- Yeoman v3
- SharePoint Framework Yeoman Generator v1.10.0

The development environment setup for macOS and Windows is demonstrated in this YouTube video: [Set up a SharePoint Framework developer environment for SharePoint Server 2019 & SE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8nLDGSnYRdY).

Additional information can be found in the companion blog post: [Definitive guide for developers: SharePoint Framework for SharePoint Server 2019](https://www.voitanos.io/blog/definitive-guide-sharepoint-framework-sharepoint-server-2019/).